# Can't understand the syntax in ocaml code

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code:

```ml
module Make_Set (Elt : EQ) : SET with type elt = Elt.t = struct
  type elt = Elt.t
  type t = elt list

  let empty = []

  let rec is_element i set =
    match set with [] -> false | x :: xs -> Elt.eq x i || is_element i xs

  let add i set = if is_element i set then set else i :: set
end
```

I can't understand the `SET with type elt = Elt.t`, nor I can find it in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The `with` constraints for module types (as described in [the tutorial part of manual](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/moduleexamples.html#s:functors-and-abstraction) and in the [reference part](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/signaturesubstitution.html)) provides a way to refine module types by adding equalities on types, modules or module types.

In your case, the constraint `SET with type elt = Elt.t` reads: the module type `SET` refined by adding the information that the type `elt` is `Elt.t`.

This is particularly useful when building types derived from other type inside a functor.
For instance, let's consider a small module type `SHOWABLE`

```ml
module type SHOWABLE = sig
  type t
  val show: t -> string
end
```

which specifies modules that provide both a type `t` and a function `show` function which convert this type to a string representation.

For instance, an implementation of this specification could be:

```ml
module Int_showable = struct
  type t = int
  let show = string_of_int
end
```

Then, if we have two modules that satisfies the `SHOW` specification, we can build a `Pair` module that build a `SHOWABLE` module from a pair of `SHOWABLE`
module:

```ml
module PAIR(X:SHOWABLE)(Y:SHOWABLE) = struct
  type t = X.t * Y.t
  let show (x,y) = String.concat "" ["(";X.show x;", "; Y.show y; ")"]
end
```

But what is the type of the resulting module?

One might be tempted to answer `SHOWABLE`.
But if we use this module type directly

```ml
module Pair(X:SHOWABLE)(Y:SHOWABLE): SHOWABLE = struct
  type t = X.t * Y.t
  let show (x,y) = String.concat "" ["("; X.show x; ", "; Y.show y; ")"]
end
module Int_Pair = Pair(Int_showable)(Int_showable)
```

we will encounter a type error as soon we try to use the `Int_pair` module:

```
let fail = Int_pair.show (1,2)
```

We get an error

```ml
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type
         Int_pair.t
```

because the constraint

```ml
module Pair(X:SHOWABLE)(Y:SHOWABLE): SHOWABLE
```

has restricted the result of `PAIR` to be exactly a `SHOWABLE`. And in the module type `SHOWABLE`, the type `t` is abstract, in other all concrete information about this type has been erased, and we don't know anymore that `Int_pair.t` is in fact `int * int`.

Thus we need a way to describe module type which is `SHOWABLE` except that the type `t` should be a pair of `X.t` and `Y.t`.

Of course, we could write that directly as:

```
module Pair(X:SHOWABLE)(Y:SHOWABLE): sig
  type t = X.t * Y.t
  val show: t -> int
end = ...
```

but then a future read might not spot the fact the resulting module also satisfies the `SHOWABLE` specification.

The `with type` constraints are a solution to this issue by providing a way to patch a previous module type by rewriting a type definition:

```
module type SHOWABLE_INT = SHOWABLE with type t = int
```

can be read: `SHOWABLE_INT` is `SHOWABLE` except that `type t = int`. In other words, `SHOWABLE_INT` is

```ml
module type SHOWABLE_INT = sig
  type t = int
  val show: t -> int
end
```

This gives us an easy way to write down the type of the `Pair` functor:

```
module Pair(X:SHOWABLE)(Y:SHOWABLE): SHOWABLE with type t = X.t * Y.t = ...
```

And once, we have added back the right type equality, the previous error is gone:

```
module Int_Pair = Pair(Int_showable)(Int_showable)
let ok = Int_pair.show (1,2)
```

and `ok` is bound to `"(1, 2)"`.

Answer (score -3):

It surely can be found in the official documentation, but more beginner friendly is the corresponding chapter 11 of "Real World OCaml". There is a new edition of this book from 2022.

It can be read here: https://dev.realworldocaml.org/toc.html